When using editorwindow script in unity3d , why all the toggles stay small?
the two buttons and all the checkboxes and the dropdown on the left they are all small while other ui elements resized fine.
i want the buttons and the checkboxes and the dropdown to be at the same size like the Settings and Item1
screenshot showing the problem:

the part with the toggle's in the OnGUI
GUIStyle customToggleStyle = new GUIStyle(GUI.skin.toggle)
{
    fontSize = Mathf.RoundToInt(14 * uiScale)
};

// Use the custom style for each Toggle
addLineNumbers = EditorGUILayout.Toggle("Add Line Numbers", addLineNumbers, 
customToggleStyle);
addEmptyLines = EditorGUILayout.Toggle("Add Empty Lines", addEmptyLines, 
customToggleStyle);
saveToFile = EditorGUILayout.Toggle("Save to File", saveToFile, customToggleStyle);
autoSave = EditorGUILayout.Toggle("Auto Save", autoSave, customToggleStyle);

the completed OnGUI code:
private void OnGUI()
{
    // Adjust the label width and field width based on the scaling factor
    EditorGUIUtility.labelWidth = 150 * uiScale;
    EditorGUIUtility.fieldWidth = 100 * uiScale;

    // Begin the main vertical layout
    EditorGUILayout.BeginVertical(GUILayout.Width(position.width), GUILayout.Height(position.height));

    // Scroll view
    scrollPos = EditorGUILayout.BeginScrollView(scrollPos, GUILayout.ExpandHeight(true));

    GUIStyle textAreaStyle = new GUIStyle(GUI.skin.textArea)
    {
        fontSize = Mathf.RoundToInt(14 * uiScale),
        wordWrap = true
    };
    Texts = EditorGUILayout.TextArea(Texts, textAreaStyle, GUILayout.ExpandHeight(true), GUILayout.Width(position.width - 20));

    EditorGUILayout.EndScrollView();

    // Space between elements
    EditorGUILayout.Space();

    // Horizontal layout for buttons with dynamic scaling for height
    EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
    if (GUILayout.Button("Add Line", GUILayout.Height(30 * uiScale)))
    {
        AddNewLine();
    }
    if (GUILayout.Button("Save", GUILayout.Height(30 * uiScale)))
    {
        SaveToFile(Text);
    }
    EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();

    // Space between elements
    EditorGUILayout.Space();

    // Settings with dynamic scaling for label font size
    GUIStyle labelStyle = new GUIStyle(GUI.skin.label) { fontSize = Mathf.RoundToInt(14 * uiScale) };
    EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Settings", labelStyle);

    GUIStyle customToggleStyle = new GUIStyle(GUI.skin.toggle)
    {
        fontSize = Mathf.RoundToInt(14 * uiScale)
    };

    // Use the custom style for each Toggle
    addLineNumbers = EditorGUILayout.Toggle("Add Line Numbers", addLineNumbers, customToggleStyle);
    addEmptyLines = EditorGUILayout.Toggle("Add Empty Lines", addEmptyLines, customToggleStyle);
    saveToFile = EditorGUILayout.Toggle("Save to File", saveToFile, customToggleStyle);
    autoSave = EditorGUILayout.Toggle("Auto Save", autoSave, customToggleStyle);

    // Dropdown menu
    GUIStyle popupStyle = new GUIStyle(EditorStyles.popup) { fontSize = Mathf.RoundToInt(14 * uiScale) };
    EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck();
    this._selected = EditorGUILayout.Popup("My Simple Dropdown", _selected, _options, popupStyle, GUILayout.Height(30 * uiScale));
    if (EditorGUI.EndChangeCheck())
    {
        Debug.Log(_options[_selected]);
    }

    // Space between elements
    EditorGUILayout.Space();

    // Show save indicator if necessary
    if (showSaveIndicator)
    {
        EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Nsaved successfully!", labelStyle);
        if ((DateTime.Now - lastSaveTime).TotalSeconds > 2)
        {
            showSaveIndicator = false;
        }
    }

    EditorGUILayout.EndVertical();
}


Well I suspect that the size of the checker is not controlled by fontSize then
